# how to use window.location in unit test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am testing one controller function .I used  `window.location`  But I am not sure are the test cases need to write ?

I write this code

```
 $scope.abc='test1'
    var params ={name:'pqr',class:'sss'}
     var location = window.location;
        document.location = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + '?' +
            $.param(params);
  }
```

here is my plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZEnWMOJo6qVhjntQM6RD?p=info

what are tests need to write ? how to test document.location ?
test.js

```
describe('value check',function(){
  var $scope,
  ctrl,
  cntrl,
  $httpBackend;
  beforeEach(function(){
    module('app');

  });


beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$controller) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();  

       cntrl = $controller('cntrl', {'$scope' : $scope });


}));



   it("check variable", function() {
     $scope.test();
     expect($scope.abc).toEqual('test1')
  });


})
```

Comment: Use the $window and $document services instead. Use dependency injection to get them, and inject mocks in your test.

Comment: I used $window and $document ..but how to test param  ? http://plnkr.co/edit/Xqptw3m5wcWljO5fy15I?p=preview

Comment: You didn't mock the services. See http://plnkr.co/edit/nUeGP0T5mqF1WhWkL14g?p=preview. There is a bug in your code BTW. The spec result makes it clear.

Comment: thanks for help what is issue ? why this test is fails ?

Comment: Just read the error message: `Expected 'http//fake.host.com/foo?name=pqr&class=sss' to be 'http://fake.host.com/foo?name=pqr&class=sss'`. There is a subtle, but important differences between the two URLs.